# API to detect distance between Wear watch & Android phone?

Tags: android, distance, wear-os

In my application, we want to warn the user when he is at distance from Phone or watch.

We are scanning nearest nodes using APIs of wear OS.

Is there any way I can detect the distance between two such nodes?

Getting geolocation of both & calculate distance using formula is one possible way.

But aren't the APIs on wear OS has something which can detect distance using Bluetooth range or signal strength?

Comment: I think you are looking for the the [position sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position) specifically the proximity sensor "*The Android platform provides two sensors that let you determine the position of a device: the geomagnetic field sensor and the accelerometer. The Android platform also provides a sensor that lets you determine how close the face of a device is to an object (known as the proximity sensor)*". You may also be interested to check for the [bluetooth network](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth).

Comment: The proximity sensor is about a phone's proximity to the user's face, **not** the proximity of two devices to each other.

Answer (score 0):

The best that's directly supported by the platform is [the Node API's `isNearby` method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Node.html#isNearby()), but that essentially just returns true iff the phone-watch connection is over Bluetooth rather than cellular or wifi. It doesn't give you anything resembling a real distance number.

Beyond that, you'd have to roll your own solution using GPS on both devices, as you mention. But that has a lot of downsides: complexity, reliability, and battery use are ones that immediately occur to me. Someday, you'll be able to get this kind of accuracy from the fused location provider [using wifi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vywGgSrGODU), but probably not for some years.